# What does IUrlHistoryStg::BindToObject Method do?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, browser-history, bho, address-bar

I'm looking for a way to access the address bar search so that i can append some personnal url at the end of the current list, and i found 'IUrlHistoryStg::BindToObject' but there is no documention linked to it. Anyone knows what this method does ?
On msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767718%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented, so it doesn't do anything.  It was a bad idea that didn't get removed in time to not have it be in the SDK.

Use [IShellFolder::BindToObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775059(VS.85).aspx) instead.